# Error "The specified application package does not exist." While checking that if azure batch application package is exists or not from azure cli?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, bitbucket-pipelines, azure-batch, azure-cli2

I want to create an application package via bit-bucket deployment  pipeline and I want to check that the same application package name and version is already available or not.

- If available, then I want to update package-file in it.
- If Not available, then want to create new one

But, If application package is not available then getting an error "**The specified application package does not exist.**"

How to get rid of this error and go ahead with package creation step even if application package is available?

Here is Azure CLI Script written in my bit-bucket deployment pipeline

```
id=$(az batch application package show --application-name testName1 --name testAppName1  --resource-group testResourceGroup1  --version-name 3.0.2556955) 
if [ "$id" == "" ]; then 
echo "Application not available then creating new with same version number - 3.0.2556955"
az batch application package create  --resource-group testResourceGroup1  --name testAppName1  --application-name testName1 --package-file test1.zip --version-name 3.0.2556955
else 
echo "Application available then append the package file in it"
echo $id
az batch application package create  --resource-group testResourceGroup1  --name testAppName1   --application-name testName1  --package-file test1.zip --version-name 3.0.2556955
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative to check this would be the [az batch application package list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch/application/package?view=azure-cli-latest#az_batch_application_package_list) command.

Example:

```
id=$(az batch application package list --application-name testName1 --name testAppName1 --resource-group testResourceGroup1 --query "[?name=='<version-number>'].id" --output tsv)
```

This would yield the resource id of the application if present, else be empty (unlike the `az batch application package show` command that gives a **ValidationError** as above).